# Apache kylin login issue

Tags: kylin

I am using apache-kylin 2.2.0v. From today morning, I am unable to connect kylin web interface. It's throwing error like `unable to login`, `please check username and password`. I didn't change any credentials. I am using default username and password only ADMIN/KYLIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

satish pujara.
It may be your Hbase not in health, Kylin has the inaccurate message for the login error condition before 2.5v, you can check this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KYLIN-3565 for details.
You can ask the question in Kylin mail list, at first you should subscribe, please refer to http://kylin.apache.org/community/.